# Отправить содержимое csv/pandas df в сообщение telebot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, telebot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли отправить содержимое csv/pandas df в сообщение telebot? Датафрейм/csv выглядят следующим образом:

```html
Номертижня      Деньтижня     Пара      1 група
Перший тиждень    Понеділок     1       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція"
                                          вул.Чигоріна,57-а .
                            2       Лб1 Практичний курс"Бізнес-симуляція"
                                          вул.Чигоріна,57-а .
                            3   
...
```

Строк в нем может быть много, до 150ед, и отправить просто csv файл нельзя.

Когда просто пытаюсь отправить df как сообщение таким способом:`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, schedule_df_group.to_string())`, то выдает такую вот ошибку:
[image]

Если возможно, то отправить сообщение в чатбот в виде таблицы

Comment: На приложенном снимке сказано, что текст, который вы отправили - слишком длинный. Максимальная длина сообщения в Telegram - 4096 символов UTF-8. У вас не получится обойти это ограничение - придется разбивать текст на несколько сообщений.

Comment: Нашел выход, превратил датафрейм в картинку)